# How to detect if a line and a line segment intersect using two points from the line and the two endpoints of the line segment

Tags: java

I have to write a Java program that reads a line and a line segment and then determines whether they intersect or not. When they overlap completely, consider that as intersecting. Use variables ((lp1x, lp1y), (lp2x, lp2y)) to represent a line and ((sp1x, sp1y), (sp2x, sp2y)) to represent a line segment. I have defined four cases (both lines are vertical, two cases for if the line is vertical and the line segment isn't and vice versa, and if neither line are vertical). I just need to know how to detect if the lines intersect or not. Coding language is Java on NetBeansIDE. Thank you in advance!

So far I have this:

```
    if(lp1x == lp2x){
        //line is vertical
        if(sp1x == sp2x){
            //line segment is vertical (case 1)
            System.out.println("case 1");
        }
        else{
            //case 2
            System.out.println("case 2");
        }
    }
    else{
        //line is not vertical
        if(sp1x == sp2x){
            //line segment is vertical (case 3)
            System.out.println("case 3");
        }
        else{
            //case 4, neither are vertical
            System.out.println("case 4");

        }
    }
```